# SAPUI5 change json file

Tags: json, model, sapui5

I have create a json file config.json and a json exteded class to manager this json file.

Basically I'd like to read and update this file.

To read:

```
init : function(fnSuccess, scope) {
    this.setDefaultBindingMode(sap.ui.model.BindingMode.TwoWay);
    this.loadData("conf.json");

    this.attachRequestCompleted(function() {
        window.url = this.getProperty("/config/url");
        window.port = this.getProperty("/config/port");
        window.ldap = this.getProperty("/config/ldap");

        if(typeof fnSuccess === 'function')
            fnSuccess(scope);
    });

},
```

It worked fine!

Now, to update the file:

```
save: function(url, port, ldap){

    if(url != null)
        this.setProperty("/config/url", url);
    if(port != null)
        this.setProperty("/config/port", port);
    if(ldap != null)
        this.setProperty("/config/ldap", ldap);

    console.log(this.getJSON());
}
```

The `console.log(this.getJSON())` print my changed JSON model, but when I reload or open the conf.json file, nothing was changed!

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't have a client browser write to file directly, you need some middleware (servlet, Gateway, etc) to handle file writing

Comment: If you want to store information on the client, you can use localstorage - but writing to files (which are on the server, anyway) is not possible from JavaScript directly.

Comment: Hi guys! Thanks for reply. I'm using the cordova file to manager this conf file. But I'm still with some doubt. Could you check this another post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679854/sapui5-using-cordova-file-to-create-config-file Thanks again.

Comment: Isn't this question already solved by [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679854/sapui5-using-cordova-file-to-create-config-file)?