# SAPUI5 using cordova file to create config file

Tags: android, cordova, sapui5

I'm try to create a config file to keep some configurations of my app. I'm using SAPUI5 and cordova file.

The intention is create a conf.txt to keep the URL, PORT and LDAP data to access my system. However, these information can change, so I need to update the file.

In my app, I've made the function deviceready when the application starts, and created the conf.txt:

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    /*jQuery.sap.require("model.Config");

    var conf = new Configuration();

    conf.init();*/

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("conf.txt", {create : true,exclusive : false},gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    //alert(fileEntry.fullPath);
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
        alert("OK");
    };
    var conf = "URL=\r\nPORT=80\r\nLDAP=false";
    writer.seek(writer.length);
    writer.write(conf);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert(error.code);
}
```

I didn't do nothing different of other examples. But, as I've commented in `onDeviceReady` function, I tried to create a class to use to create the file, read and update it.

All examples that I found reference the deviceready event. Can I just use the methods of FileWriter and FileReader on this event?

It's my Configuration Class:

```
function Configuration() {
    this.fileName = "conf.txt";

    this.init = function() {**How to use the cordova API here**};

    this.read = function(){**How to use the cordova API here**};

    this.update= function(){**How to use the cordova API here**};

}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Could you just store these values in a .json file when you bundle the app?  As far as the values changing, you can just persist the new values in local storage.  This strategy seems a lot simpler than worrying about persisting values to the file system in a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Njtman, I got to save the informations in file without cordova file plugin just using `localstorage`.

I'd like to share the solution found.

index.html on deviceready event:

```
jQuery.sap.require("model.Config");

var conf = new Configuration();

sap.ui.getCore().setModel(conf, "Config");

conf.init();
```

Configuration class:

```
sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.extend("Configuration", {

url: "",
port: "80",
defaultport: true,
ldap: false,

init : function() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    console.log("INITIALIZING...");

    var config = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("config"));

    if(config == null){
        console.log("CONFIG IS NULL");
        window.localStorage.setItem("config", JSON.stringify(
                {"URL": this.url, "PORT": this.port, "DEFAULTPORT": this.defaultport, "LDAP": this.ldap}
            ));         
    }

    deferred.resolve();
    this.setData(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("config")));
    this.setVars();

    console.log(this.getJSON());

    return deferred.promise();
},

save: function(url, port, defaultport, ldap){

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    console.log("SAVING...");

    window.localStorage.setItem("config", JSON.stringify(
           {"URL": url, "PORT": port, "DEFAULTPORT": defaultport, "LDAP": ldap}
        ));

    deferred.resolve();
    this.setData(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("config")));

    this.setVars();

    return deferred.promise();

},

setVars: function(){
    this.url = this.getProperty("/URL");
    this.port = this.getProperty("/PORT");
    this.defaultport = this.getProperty("/DEFAULTPORT");
    this.ldap = this.getProperty("/LDAP");

}
});
```

Now I can read and update my json file.